# Creating a oneliner to import database

Tags: linux, ubuntu, awk, grep, cut

Im trying to make a oneliner in Linux that will collect database host, database name, username and password from `wp-config.php` and combine that into a line where i can import a database with a `.sh` file.

The block of code I need to collect is:

```
/** The name of the database for WordPress */
define('DB_NAME', 'database_name_here');

/** MySQL database username */
define('DB_USER', 'username_here');

/** MySQL database password */
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'password_here');

/** MySQL hostname */
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
```

The line I'm trying to create is:

`mysql -h localhost -u username_here --password="password_here" database_name_here < db-backup.sql`

I'm new to this so what i have tried to do is:

`grep DB_HOST DB_USER wp-config.php | cut -d "'" -f4 | awk '{print "mysql -h "$0;}'` This start is working, but when i want to add more info to the string im just getting the last part.

How do I write this to get a full row with all information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
MYSQLPWD=$(cat wp-config.php |grep DB_PASSWORD | cut -d \' -f 4)
MYSQLUSR=$(cat wp-config.php |grep DB_USER | cut -d \' -f 4)
MYSQLDBNAME=$(cat wp-config.php |grep DB_NAME | cut -d \' -f 4)
HT="localhost"

echo $MYSQLPWD
echo $MYSQLUSR
echo $MYSQLDBNAME
echo $HT

mysql -h$HT -u$MYSQLUSR -p$MYSQLPWD $MYSQLDBNAME <  $MYSQLDBNAME
```

Answer (score 0):

not a one-liner, but works for your simple example

```
DB_PASSWORD=$(grep DB_PASSWORD wp-config.php | cut -d "'" -f4)
DB_USER=$(grep DB_USER wp-config.php | cut -d "'" -f4)
DB_NAME=$(grep DB_NAME wp-config.php | cut -d "'" -f4)
DB_HOST=$(grep DB_HOST wp-config.php | cut -d "'" -f4)

echo "mysql -h $DB_HOST -u $DB_USER --password=\"$DB_PASSWORD\" $DB_NAME"
```

Few notes: you do not need awk, you used it to just concatenate strings, so I removed it. And the detection of the relevant lines in the input file is not perfect, it may be confused by many things, for example if there is a comment in the input file

```
/** we are using blabla as DB_NAME because <reasons> **/
```

It would detect that line as matching for DB_NAME. 
Also, it is important to have exactly one matching line.